# I have two functions, when I run the program only the button click counter function seems to run. They both work individually

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm looking for a way to make both the functions run together. The idea is that the button clicked generates a random number between 1-20. This is then sent to a if statement which displays a different piece of text depending on whether it is below or equal to 10 or above. This works fine on its own. Then I added in the button click counter (which also works fine on its own) I created for the code, to count how many times the button was clicked as it generates a new number for the user. This now results in only the button clicks being counted and not displaying the random number generated or the text to go with it anymore. I'm sure this is a simple fix. Could someone help and give a little explanation on where I went wrong? thank you to anyone who helped.

First I will display a version with comments and all for any beginner level coder looking for something with more explanation. Then a bare code version for anyone looking for something with less mess.

```
//Commented Version:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Random Number Generator with Button Counter</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--This is the button that calls the function ranNum()-->
    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" id="btn" value="Generate Random 
    Number Between 1 and 20" />

    <!--Here is where the Randomly Generated Number is stored in numText 
    and the text to go with it.-->
    <p id="numText"></p>

    <!--Here is where the number of times the button has been clicked is 
    stored.-->
    <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>


     <script>

        window.onload = function () {

          /*Generates a random number from 1 to 20. this number is carried 
          into the IF statement using the variable name GenerateNumber. The 
          if statement checks if the number is less than or equal to 10 and 
          gives out an appropriate response if so. If it dosen't meet the 
          criteria, it will call the else statement.
        */
            function ranNum() {

                var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

                var conclusion

                if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is 
                    less than or equal to 10`;

                } else {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is 
                    greater than 10`;

                 } //END of if statement

                //The given conclusion is taken here and stored/displayed on 
                the page using the id numText.
                document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

            } //END of ranNum

        //Global variable set to store the count.
        var count = 0;

        //Global variable set to store button count.
        var button = document.getElementById("btn");

        /*This is where the stored count is moved to be dispayed on the page 
        through the p tag with
        the id of displayCount.*/
        var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

        /*This is the function which has been to set to count on button 
        clicks and increment by 1 every time.*/
        button.onclick = function storeClickCount() {
                count++;
                display.innerHTML = count;
            }//END of storeClickCount

        }//END of window.onload

    </script>

</body>

</html>

//Version with no comments:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Random Number Generator with Button Counter</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" id="btn" value="Generate Random 
    Number Between 1 and 20" />

     <p id="numText"></p>

     <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>


     <script>

        window.onload = function () {

            function ranNum() {

                var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

                var conclusion

                if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is 
                    less than or equal to 10`;

                } else {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is 
                    greater than 10`;

                 } 

                document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

            } 

        var count = 0;

        var button = document.getElementById("btn");

        var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

        button.onclick = function storeClickCount() {
                count++;
                display.innerHTML = count;
            }

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `addEventListener()` you can bind multiple functions from within the `window.onload` scope. See my example.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function ranNum() {
    var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    var conclusion;
    if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is less than or equal to 10`;
    } else {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is greater than 10`;
    }
    document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;
  }

  var count = 0;
  var button = document.getElementById("btn");
  var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

  button.addEventListener('click',ranNum);
  button.addEventListener('click',function storeClickCount() {
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
  });

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Generate Random Number Between 1 and 20" />
<p id="numText"></p>
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer help me a lot and is something i will carry into the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ranNum` is not a global function as it is hidden within the `window.onload` callback, and so the HTML `onclick` attribute's value has no visibility on it.

Solution:

Move `ranNum` outside of the callback, into the global scope. The downside of this solution is that you keep using two ways of handling the click event: (1) via a HTML `onclick` attribute value, and (2) via a `onclick =` handler assignment in JS code. This is confusing for anyone trying to understand or manage the code.

Alternative solution:

Don't use the `onclick` attribute in HTML, but instead call `ranNum` from within the click handler you already have for `button`:

```
        button.onclick = function storeClickCount() {
            ranNum(); // <<-------
            count++;
            display.innerHTML = count;
        }
```

Advise: use the browser's console to verify for errors. It would show an error there when you click the button and the `ranNum` function is not found.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code a bit. The whole process is contained in one `function()` instead of two separate `functions()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Random Number Generator with Button Counter</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" id="btn" value="Generate Random 
    Number Between 1 and 20" />

     <p id="numText"></p>

     <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>


     <script>

            var numText = document.getElementById("numText");
            var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");
            var count = 0;

            function ranNum() {

                var generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
                count++;
                var conclusion = '';

                if (generatedNumber <= 10) {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${generatedNumber} is 
                    less than or equal to 10`;

                } else {

                    conclusion = `The number generated ${generatedNumber} is 
                    greater than 10`;

                 } 

                numText.innerHTML = conclusion;
                displayCount.innerHTML = count;

            };

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a nice way of doing things, thank you! I also appreciate seeing different ways of coding the same task to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are! I just created a fuction for you button's click which contain your two functions ;) Good luck

https://codepen.io/greg_o/pen/dgxgKL?editors=1111

```js
window.onload = function(){
let count = 0;
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
var display=document.getElementById("displayCount");

function storeClickCount() {
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
  };


function ranNum() {
    let GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    let conclusion;

    if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is less than or equal to 10`;
    } else {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is greater than 10`;
    }

    document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;
  }

ranNum();

button.onclick = function buttonClick(){
    ranNum();
    storeClickCount()
}}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" id="btn" value="Generate Random 
    Number Between 1 and 20" />

<p id="numText"></p>

<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: In my opinion It's not a bad practice to do element manipulation triggered on the window.onload event. In case of code refactoring (to for example external js file) you would not need to change the the js code.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know, I will edit then with onload. May you can explain me what would be the problem in case of refractoring ? I have to say that I don't see the issue ?

Comment: I was not saying that you where wrong, I just disagreed to your statement (which you edited away) that putting the code in a `window.onload` event makes it unnecessarily confusing. Even though his code doesn't need the event handler (because the script is placed after the corresponding html elements) I don't think it's a bad practice to do so anyway. It's almost no impact on performance and it's a good habit to place code that uses these elements within this event in my opinion. It's not very complicated either. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: Placing just the function `ranNum()` outside the onload handler would be wise though I think.